# Why XCUITest is working too much slow for iOS app?

Tags: selenium, automation, appium, xcuitest

I want to get value of dynamic element in the iOS native app. I used `XCUITest` to get path of the element. Path is working fine but its taking approx 1 minute to get/print the value. I didn't use any wait.

My Code is:

```
String El1="//XCUIElementTypeApplication[@name='appName']/XCUIElementTypeWindow[1]/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeTable/XCUIElementTypeCell[5]/XCUIElementTypeStaticText";

 System.out.println("Value: "+driver.findElementByXPath(El1).getText());
```

Answer (score 1):

The XCTest is quite fast framework. 
Though Xpath is very common and flexible, it is not the best option to find iOS elements. 
You shall shorten you query for this element and use `findElementByIosNsPredicate`

`IOSElement settingsCell = driver.findElementByIosNsPredicate("type == 'XCUIElementTypeCell' AND name == 'Settings'");`

You will probably find this article helpful

http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/ios/ios-predicate/

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that your xpath string is very long. This tends to slow down Appium as it needs to traverse the long path in your case. It is very brittle and bad idea to put absolute xpath too.

There are a few ways to get the element

class name 
id 
name
xpath
accessibility id
ios predicate string
ios class chain

Refer to your inspector (example Appium Inspector) on the element. 
If there is a accessible id , the code should be

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(MobileBy.AccessibilityID("foo"));
```

Class Name

Class Name should be the second in line. This is effective especially if there are only 1 unique classname - like there is only 1 button in the form

```
List<MobileElement> elementsTwo = (List<MobileElement>) driver.findElementsByClassName("XCUIElementTypeButton");
```

iOS-specific Locator Strategies

 
You can try the iOSClassChain. That is the next effective selector. Example

```
String selector = "**/XCUIElementTypeCell[`name BEGINSWITH "C"`]/XCUIElementTypeButton[10]";<br>
driver.findElement(MobileBy.iOSClassChain(selector));
```

Or you can try with predicate selector.

```
driver.findElementsByIosNsPredicate("isWDVisible == 1");
```

Finally if all these options run out , you should use xpath as last resort. Avoid absolute xpath and use relative xpath.

Absolute xpath

```
String El1="//XCUIElementTypeApplication[@name='appName']/XCUIElementTypeWindow[1]/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeTable/XCUIElementTypeCell[5]/XCUIElementTypeStaticText";
```

Relative xpath

```
String El1 = “//XCUIElementTypeTable[name=‘Customer’]/XCUIElementTypeCell[5]/XCUIElementTypeStaticText”
```